# Any way to export/import ini-files, articles, etc to XLIFF?

Tags: translation

As title, we need to translate our Joomla site. We have a bunch of home-made components, so those ini-files should be possible to export/import too, but also stuff from the database. The file should then be send to an external translator, like translated.net. Anyone else faced this problem?

I've checked out a number of already existing components to deal with this, like jDiction, Freestyle Translation Manager and FaLang, but I think I would have to Frankenstein them together to get something that's really useful for us and our workflow.

Comment: http://neno-translate.com and https://gtranslate.io/ might be worth a look. I don't really know though, hence comment only.

Comment: @oooooo Thank you. Yes, I checked Neno and it seems very complete, might be working for us.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like http://neno-translate.com is a perfect match for you. Does exactly that!

Comment: It has no export function, though, as far as I can tell. Probably because they couldn't earn money if it had.

Comment: Why does it need an export function. It allows you to translate within the program or outsource translation. To export why not just FTPnthe in files?

Comment: Link to Neno is now broken.